# Org-mode insert link in source code block

Tags: emacs, publish, org-mode

I want to insert an link in my source code comment in the org-mode source code block. For example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
 ;this is the comment part, I want to insert a clickable link here.
#+END_SRC
```

I tried `src_org{[[link][description]]}`, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org-mode clickable links are generally activated using `C-c C-o` (`org-open-at-point`) or by clicking on the link with the mouse (`org-open-at-mouse`). Note that neither command is specific to URLs; like most of Org, their functionality is dependent on the context of their use. Inside a code block, these commands execute the code block.

The `src_<language>{}` inline code block syntax cannot be used to embed Org code inside a code block.

One workaround is to use `browse-url` while point is on the URL you wish to visit:

```lisp
;; Does something interesting, see http://google.com/
;;                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;;                         With point at any of these positions
```

Of course, you can bind this command to any key you wish.

From `C-h f browse-url`:

> Ask a WWW browser to load URL.
>
> Prompts for a URL, defaulting to the URL at or before point.  Variable `browse-url-browser-function` says which browser to use. If the URL is a mailto: URL, consult `browse-url-mailto-function` first, if that exists.

Comment: Your answer is to open a url in the org mode. This is not I mean, for two reasons: 1.If I have a very long url, like the url of this question. It would be too lengthy to include in the comment. 2. When I  publish into the html file, the url is still not clickable in the code block.

Comment: @luming, nowhere in your question do you mention exporting to HTML. Perhaps you should add more detail about what you want. Are you exporting the whole Org buffer to HTML? Just the code blocks? Do you ever intend to tangle the file into pure code files? If so, how should the links appear in the exported code files?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe my question clearly. I am exporting the whole content of my org file to html, the org file has some code blocks any other normal text part; I want to add some reference link in the code block comment which is clickable and should not be too long. @Chris

Comment: @buzhidao Finally did you find a solution? I would like to do the same: code block with working org mode links.

Comment: @buzhidao ok, thanks for the feedback. AFAIK there is a solution for "org-mode link -> code position" (see: http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html) but not the reverse (your initial question). On my side I will still use org-mode, but I think this would be an interesting feature to add.